# Why is the output from Unquote missing in my F# unit test failures?

Tags: f#, f#-unquote

I have a unit test written in F# that uses the Unquote library to do the assertions like so:

```
module Iccm

open System
open NUnit.Framework
open Swensen.Unquote

[<TestCase("0000000000000000000000000546314", "http://...er.aspx?FolderID=0000000000000000000000000546314")>]
[<TestCase("0000000000000000000000000535126", "http://...er.aspx?FolderID=0000000000000000000000000535126")>]
[<TestCase("0000000000000000000000000545845", "http://...er.aspx?FolderID=0000000000000000000000000545845")>]
[<TestCase("0000000000000000000000000364684", "http://...er.aspx?FolderID=0000000000000000000000000364684")>]
let ``callLink returns complete Uri with given eFolderId embedded`` 
    eFolderId expectedUri =
    test <@ Iccm.callLink eFolderId = expectedUri @>
```

Very good so far. I make the tests fail so I can see how Unquote progressively reveals the evaluation of the quoted expressions but I am not getting the unquote report in my test runner console

```
C:\TFS\SANDBOX_2456764.0\PrototypeWorkspace\IccmToTfs\src\IccmToTfs.Console.Tests\bin\Debug>"C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.4\bin\nunit-console-x86.exe" IccmToTfs.
Console.Tests.dll
NUnit-Console version 2.6.4.14350
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Charlie Poole.
Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
All Rights Reserved.

Runtime Environment -
   OS Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
  CLR Version: 2.0.50727.5485 ( Net 3.5 )

ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Single
Execution Runtime: net-3.5
.F.F.F.F.......
Tests run: 11, Errors: 4, Failures: 0, Inconclusive: 0, Time: 0.319073211837137 seconds
  Not run: 0, Invalid: 0, Ignored: 0, Skipped: 0

Errors and Failures:
1) Test Error : Iccm.callLink returns complete Uri with given eFolderId embedded("0000000000000000000000000545845","http://usas25/esdSSO/eExternalForm.asp?service=IC
CM%20e-Service%20Desk&redirect=http://usas25/esd/eFolder.aspx?FolderID=0000000000000000000000000545845%2526client=external%2526Service=ICCM+e-Service+Desk")
   System.ArgumentException : Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Uri'.
   at System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast)
   at System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Object[] parameters, Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature sig)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at NUnit.Core.Reflect.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object fixture, Object[] args)
   at NUnit.Core.TestMethod.RunTestMethod()
   at NUnit.Core.TestMethod.RunTestCase(TestResult testResult)

2) Test Error : Iccm.callLink returns complete Uri with given eFolderId embedded("0000000000000000000000000546314","http://usas25/esdSSO/eExternalForm.asp?service=IC
CM%20e-Service%20Desk&redirect=http://usas25/esd/eFolder.aspx?FolderID=0000000000000000000000000546314%2526client=external%2526Service=ICCM+e-Service+Desk")
   System.ArgumentException : Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Uri'.
   at System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast)
   at System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Object[] parameters, Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature sig)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at NUnit.Core.Reflect.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object fixture, Object[] args)
   at NUnit.Core.TestMethod.RunTestMethod()
   at NUnit.Core.TestMethod.RunTestCase(TestResult testResult)
```

I tried both NUnit on the command line and ReSharper within Visual Studio 2013 and neither one seems to know how to read the Unquote output. Does anyone know why? Is there a different test runner that I must use for Unquote to work properly?

**Update:**

This other test case has a failure and demonstrates the Unquote output very nicely:

```
[<TestCase(3s, "03/02/2015", 3150202)>]
let ``callPriority returns expected integer given a priority and date``
    priority dateString expectedInteger =
    let date = DateTime.Parse(dateString)
    test <@ Iccm.callPriority priority date = expectedInteger @>
```

Output from Unquote:

```
Iccm.callPriority 3s 3/2/2015 12:00:00 AM = 3150202
3150302 = 3150202
false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the error messages, including the call stack, you'll see that the exceptions are thrown by the NUnit test runner.

The body of the test is never executed, because:

> Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Uri'.

The values in the `[TestCase]` attributes are `string` values, but it looks like the F# compiler has inferred one of the arguments to be `Uri` instances.

My guess is that it's the `eFolderId` argument that's inferred to be a `Uri` value, because it's being used as a function argument. Unfortunately, we don't know what the type of the `Iccm.callLink` function is, so this is only a guess.

With one or both arguments (`eFolderId` or `expectedUri`) statically typed as `Uri`, and the run-time types of the `[TestCase]` values as `string` values, the .NET runtime will attempt to convert `string` into `Uri`.

There's no implicit conversion from `string` to `Uri`, and this is the reason the exception is thrown.

Unquote is not even involved at this point.

Comment: Hi Mark, Yes the callLink function returns Uri. The passing test uses the expression `test <@ Iccm.callLink eFolderId = new Uri(expectedUri) @>`. I removed the new Uri just to force an error and see what Unquote would tell me. I guess the failure has to be a little more subtle before it gets that far.